# How to get Sum of numbers for for date range for each year in PL/SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query. I want to get sum of quantity for each year like 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013. It is working for
`a.sale_date between '01-JAN-2010' and '31-DEC-2010'`

but not for
`a.sale_date between '01-JAN-2010' and '31-DEC-2018'`

```
  SELECT c.tnama, SUM (a.net_weight)
    FROM sales a,
         invoice b,
         buy c,
         estate d
   WHERE     a.sale_date BETWEEN '01-JAN-2010' AND '31-DEC-2018'
         AND b.estate_code = d.estate_code
         AND d.estate_code = '023'
         AND b.actual_sale_year = a.sale_year
         AND b.actual_sale_no = a.sale_no
         AND b.lot_no = a.lot_no
         AND c.t$cuno = a.buyer_code
GROUP BY c.tnama
ORDER BY 1, 2 DESC
```

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] including DDL statements for your tables, DML statements for some sample data and your query's expected output for that sample data.

Comment: in this out put i get between '01-JAN-2010' and '31-DEC-2010' the quantity total for the 2010

Comment: like in with column headings 2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018

Answer (score 1):

> get sum of quantity for each year

means that you should actually *select* that year from the `SALE_DATE` column and include it into the `GROUP BY` clause.

Also, although not related to your question, you should rather use `DATE` datatype values in the `WHERE` clause, such as

- date literals, e.g. `date '2018-12-31`', or
- `TO_DATE` function, e.g. `to_date('31.12.2018', 'dd.mm.yyyy')`,
- but not **strings**, e.g. `'01-JAN-2010'`

---

```
  SELECT c.tnama, 
         EXTRACT (YEAR FROM a.sale_date) c_year,    --> this 
         SUM (a.net_weight)
    FROM sales a,
         invoice b,
         buy c,
         estate d
   WHERE     a.sale_date BETWEEN DATE '2010-01-01'  --> use dates, not strings 
                             AND DATE '2018-12-31'
         AND b.estate_code = d.estate_code
         AND d.estate_code = '023'
         AND b.actual_sale_year = a.sale_year
         AND b.actual_sale_no = a.sale_no
         AND b.lot_no = a.lot_no
         AND c.t$cuno = a.buyer_code
GROUP BY c.tnama, 
         EXTRACT (YEAR FROM a.sale_date)            --> has to be included into the GROUP BY clause
ORDER BY 1, 2 DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to have the year in separate columns, use PIVOT.

I have used fictitious data for demonstration, change as per your requirement.

```
WITH t
     AS (SELECT sales_value, TO_CHAR (sale_date, 'YYYY') sale_date
           FROM pivot_tab)
SELECT *
  FROM t PIVOT (SUM (sales_value) FOR sale_date IN ('2015', '2016')) yr
```

Result

```
╔══════╦═══════╗
║ 2015 ║ 2016  ║
╠══════╬═══════╣
║ 6000 ║ 10000 ║
╚══════╩═══════╝
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1cf1d1/9)